# Git showing changes from other projects

Tags: git

I have three projects in my /rails directory:  test_app/, dma4/ and test2_app/.  I am currently working in the test_app/ directory (which is already initialized for git) and committed the changes.  After commiting, I did a 'git status' to see the changes.  For some reason it tells me that there are no changes, EXCEPT for ../dma4 and ../test2_app which are other projects!!

Why would it tell me about changes outside of my current project??  I shouldn't have to ignore other projects in my .gitignore file...

Here's the exact message:

```
test_app $ git status
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   ../dma4 (modified content)
#   modified:   ../test2_app (modified content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
test_app $
```

These other projects are not subfolders for the current project, here's how the heirarchy looks:

rails/test2_app
rails/dma4
rails/test_app

Why would it do this??

Comment: What is the output of `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`?

Comment: I wish I tried your command but before refreshing stackoverflow I did ls -la ../ and saw .git in the parent directory for all of my apps!  Some how I mistakenly ran 'git init .' inside of the parent directory!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initialized your Git repository one level too high up in the directory tree. If you go up a level and do an `ls -a`, you'll probably see a `.git` there.

Try going into the actual folder of your project and doing `git init` there instead.

Comment: That's what it was - is it safe to just 'rm -rf .git' in the parent directory?  Not sure if git adds more '.git' folders around the rest of the project subfolders, although I have not found any.

Comment: Yes, it's safe (assuming you don't care about any saved commits or whatnot) - Git is very self-contained in a single .git directory.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the project directory if you're using VS code and type 'git init'.

This works